# mariadb-where is open_files_limit parameter set?

Tags: centos, mysql, apache-2.4, mariadb

I have `LAMP` with `CentOS 8` and `MariaDB` installed on my server. in PHPMyAdmin I need to increase `open files limit` parameter, which is disabled and cannot be edited from there. its current value is set to 16,​384. I checked the hard and soft limits of the server:

```
ulimit -Hn
262144


ulimit -Sn
1024

cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
199584
```

moreover I checked `/etc/security/limits.conf` and there was no limit mentioned there for open files. now my question is where is this 16,384 limit coming from (where is it set)? and how can I increase it?

Comment: What happens when you just set `open-files-limit` in the `mysqld` section of `my.cnf`? If that does not work, I would assume you need to tweak the systemd config for the service.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist many thanks. I added `open-files-limit=16500` below `[mysqld]` section of `server.cnf` file (which is included in my.cnf) and restarted mariadb, but the value did not change in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System wide limits for max number of open file descriptors are set in /etc/security/limits.conf with the "nofile" item.

The entries for the mysql user would look like this:

```
mysql            hard    nofile          16384
mysql            soft    nofile          16384
```

since CentOS 8 uses systemd, systemd itself might set the limit via the
"LimitNOFILE" option in the systemd service file.

check the systemd service file (most likely "/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service") for "LimitNOFILE=16384".
If you want to change the limit, don't edit this file (it might get overwritten when updating the mariadb package), copy the file to
"/etc/systemd/system/" and edit it there.

Comment: This probably also ought to cover the my.cnf setting

Comment: @Marc. amazing! worked like a charm! the only point is that there were no records for mysql in limits.conf file and so I only edited LimitNOFILE in mysql.service file as you explained. is that enough?

Comment: yes. if systemd starts the service, you only need the "LimitNOFILE" option.